# Looping through select rows based on input of one or more columns

Tags: r

I have a nested list of items such that I have 3 separate lists grouped into one. I would like to make changes to a specific column that is present in all the lists. I have more details below

> X

```
  $`Manufacturing`
    Stage           Days.Added  Start.Date  End.Date
    Planning                 2  1968-12-01  NA
    Building                14          NA  NA
    Testing                  3          NA  NA
    Implementation          15          NA  NA

  $`Project Analysis`
    Stage             Days.Added  Start.Date  End.Date
    Initial Review             3  1968-12-01  NA
    Building                  14          NA  NA
    User Testing              20          NA  NA
    Implementation            15          NA  NA
    User Review                7          NA  NA
    Final Analysis             4          NA  NA
```

> lapply(X, '[', 'End.Date') gives me:

```
  $`Manufacturing`
    End.Date
    NA
    NA
    NA
    NA


  $`Project Analysis`
    End.Date
    NA
    NA
    NA
    NA
    NA
    NA
```

I want to create a loop whereby the 'End.Date' column is the addition of the 'Start.Date' and the 'Days.Added' column for the first row. The resulting value would be the 'Start.Date' entry for the second row which would have the 'Days.Added' column added to produce the new 'End.Date' for the second row and so forth. So basically something like this:

```
  $`Manufacturing`
    Stage           Days.Added  Start.Date  End.Date
    Planning                 2  1968-12-01  1968-12-03
    Building                14  1968-12-03  1968-12-17
    Testing                  3  1968-12-17  1968-12-20
    Implementation          15  1968-12-20  1969-01-04

  $`Project Analysis`
    Stage             Days.Added  Start.Date  End.Date
    Initial Review             3  1968-12-01  1968-12-04
    Building                  15  1968-12-04  1968-12-19
    User Testing              20  1968-12-19  1969-01-08
    Implementation            15  1969-01-08  1969-01-23
    User Review                7  1969-01-23  1969-01-30
    Final Analysis             4  1969-01-30  1969-02-03
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I think you need `lapply(X, transform, End_Date = Start.Date[1]  + Days.Added)`

Comment: If you need both columns `lapply(X, transform, Start_Date = Start_Date[1] + Days_Added, End_Date = Start.Date[1]  + Days.Added)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Start.Date' is`Date` class,

```
lapply(X, transform, Start.Date = Start.Date[1] +
    c(0, cumsum(Days.Added[-length(Days.Added)])), 
         End.Date = Start.Date[1] + cumsum(Days.Added))
```

#### data

```
X <- list(Manufacturing = structure(list(Stage = c("Planning", "Building", 
"Testing", "Implementation"), Days.Added = c(2L, 14L, 3L, 15L
), Start.Date = structure(c(-396, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
    End.Date = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    `Project Analysis` = structure(list(Stage = c("Initial Review", 
    "Building", "User Testing", "Implementation", "User Review", 
    "Final Analysis"), Days.Added = c(3L, 14L, 20L, 15L, 7L, 
    4L), Start.Date = structure(c(-396, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
        End.Date = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L), class = "data.frame"))
```